# Stubbing diamond-containing classes in Android

Tags: java, android, callback, stubbing

*Edit: This question arises because I didn't realize there was a StrongLoop guide to follow. My request is for stubbing and not the StrongLoop code itself.*

I'm pretty new to Android and Java. I wanted to keep StrongLoop [sample code](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/nodejs-loopback-android-sdk-1-3/) in the project while I tested something, so I tried stubbing it (to get a build) and failed. I found and will follow the StrongLoop setup guide, but my stubbing skills are lacking.

I think this is the minimum code for my question:

```
1: // UserRepository<User> userRepo = adapter.createRepository(UserRepository<User>.class);
2: UserRepository<User> userRepo = adapter.createRepository(UserRepository.class);

3: userRepo.findCurrentUser(new ObjectCallback<User>() {
4:     public void onSuccess(User user) {}
5: });
6: userRepo.loginUser("user", "pwd",
7:     new UserRepository<User>.LoginCallback() {
```

Stub attempt:

```
public class User {}
public class UserRepository<a> {
    public void findCurrentUser(ObjectCallback a) {}
    public void loginUser(String a, String b, UserRepository c) {}
    public void onSuccess(User u) {}
    public void LoginCallback() {}
}
```

At line, note:

1. Commented; with **<User>.class** I get: "Cannot select from parameterized type". Searches tell me to read up on generic functions.
2. The rabbit I chased; I thought error #1 meant "Remove the parameter (<User>) from the type (UserRepository)".
3. findCurrentUser() resolves okay.
4. onSuccess() resolves okay.
5. .
6. loginUser() probably resolves okay.
7. "Cannot resolve symbol 'LoginCallback'"

For #2 I had to add:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked");
```

...and by the error on #7 I stopped digging the hole. It's too generic to search on without advice on what I'm breaking.

So how do I fix my stub attempt? I'll learn from that, and with go-read suggestions I'll gladly study the concepts I can't name but am certainly misusing.

- The only idea I have right now is that when the callback executes the class is gone.

Comment: The "diamond-containing class" that you mentioned is actually called [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), and it can be intimidating for new programmer. But I'm not sure I can solve it as I don't have experience in StrongLoop. I feel something is wrong with the code when compared to the [`UserRepository` API doc](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-sdk-android/api/com/strongloop/android/loopback/UserRepository.html), but not sure how to address all the issues.

Comment: I totally didn't know about the Oracle tutorial, thank you! I'm going to follow StrongLoop's setup guides, but from the perspective of stubbing, type erasure kept showing up in searches so I'll look at that more carefully.

Comment: @AndrewT. As I thought about type erasure in your link, it suddenly seemed relevant that I stubbed User. I edited to include that line.